# Difference between use Modulename; and use Modulename();

Tags: perl

Is there any difference between `use Modulename;` and `use Modulename();` ?
Sometimes I see, for example, `use Carp;` and sometimes `use Carp ();`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As [documented](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html),

```
use Modulename;
```

is the basically the same as

```
BEGIN {
   require Modulename;
   import Modulename;
}
```

while

```
use Modulename ();
```

is the basically the same as

```
BEGIN { require Modulename; }
```

That means the parens specify that you don't want to import anything. (It would also prevent a pragma from doing its work.)

---

Carp exports `confess`, `croak` and `carp` by default, so

```
use Carp;
```

is short for

```
use Carp qw( confess croak carp );
```

By using

```
use Carp ();   # or: use Carp qw( );
```

`confess`, `croak` and `carp` won't be added to the caller's namespace. They will still be available through their fully qualified name.

```
use Carp ();
Carp::croak(...);
```

Answer (score 5):

Without the `()`, the package's `import` method will be called, possibly causing some default set of names to be exported into the calling package's namespace.

Passing the `()` explicitly says "Do not import any names into my namespace."

Most modern object-oriented modules don't export anything by default anyway, and there's nothing stopping them from manually polluting the caller's namespace if they wanted to, but specifying `()` is a signal that you're not relying on names magically appearing just because you imported a package.

Answer (score 4):

From the [perlfunc documentation on `use`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html):

> If you do not want to call the package's [`import`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/import.html) method (for instance,
>   to stop your namespace from being altered), explicitly supply the
>   empty list:
>
> ```
> use Module ();
> ```
>
> That is exactly equivalent to
>
> ```
> BEGIN { require Module }
> ```

Answer (score 3):

From [perldoc -f use](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html)

> If you do not want to call the package's import method (for instance,
>   to stop your namespace from being altered), explicitly supply the
>   empty list:

`use Carp;` imports a few functions (`carp`, etc.), but `use Carp ();` does not import any functions.

Comment: It depends on how you look at it.  Carp is exporting, whatever package has the `use Carp` is importing.  Regardless, it doesn't happen if you specify `()`.